# Ignorar archivos en commits ya realizados y empujados

Tags: git, github

Quiero ignorar un archivo en commits que ya realice y empuje a github, pues al ver commit por commit de inicio a fin estoy viendo las modificaciones que se realizaron en unos archivos y no quiero tener que ver esto.  Hay alguna manera de omitir-ignorar estos archivos al ver el historial de commits?

Answer (score 3):

En caso de que aún lo necesites te dejo la solución que a mi me ha funcionado:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged '<file>'
```

Con esta línea le indicas que archivo quieres que ignore, igual en lugar de pasar archivo, le pasas la ruta de toda una carpeta.

Si se quiere dejar de ignorar:

```
git update-index --no-asume-unchaged '<file>'
```

Se puede obtener una lista de los archivos que han sido ignorados mediante el -assume-unchanged:

```
git ls-files -v|grep '^[a-z]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberias agregar al archivo .gitignore,aunque si el archivo ya está siendo versionado por Git, agregar dicho archivo a .gitignore no hará que Git deje de observarlo. En este caso necesitarás ejecutar 
git rm --cached  
para conservar el archivo y luego ignorarlo. Puedes encontrar mas informacion en el siguiente enlace [Ignorar archivos git](http://es.gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/19/ignoring-files.html)

Comment: bueno lo hice, me funciono el comando pero al entrar a github  y ver los commits hechos antes de ejecutar este comando sigo viendo archivos que quiero ignorar.

Comment: Lo seguirás viendo porque en un momento hiciste algo con ellos, aun no he encontrado la forma de ignorar archivos en el listado de commits de git, lo que hiciste fue que los archivos que ya ignoraste, aunque sufran cambios no serán subidos.