# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar un archivo del respositorio de git sin eliminarlo del disco ni perder los cambios?

Tags: git

Quiero quitar de un repositorio un archivo ".Rdata" que pesa mas de 300Mb e involucra varios commits.

¿Cómo puedo eliminarlo del repositorio git (sin eliminarlo de la carpeta local) sin perder los cambios actuales?

Nota: El repositorio no está publicado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes agregar el archivo(s) que quieres excluir a tu archivo .gitignore.

```
.Rdata
```

Si agregas la extensión del archivo, git va a excluir todos los archivos con esa extensión.

Si agregas la ruta completa al archivo, git solo va a excluir el archivo específico.

En caso de que git reconozca tu archivo antes de agregarlo al .gitignore es probable que necesites borrarlo de cache

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Remueve archivos incluidos en .gitignore"
```

Puedes leer más sobre .gitignore en https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ambas me solucionaron el problema.

Answer (score 0):

A mí me ha funcionado esto:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged '<file>'
```

Con esta línea le indicas qué archivo quieres que ignore. De la misma manera, en lugar de pasar archivo le puedes pasar la ruta de toda una carpeta.

Si se quiere dejar de ignorar:

```
git update-index --no-asume-unchaged '<file>'
```

Se puede obtener una lista de los archivos que han sido ignorados mediante el -assume-unchanged:

```
git ls-files -v|grep '^[a-z]'
```

En [Ignorar archivos en commits ya realizados y empujados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15551/ignorar-archivos-en-commits-ya-realizados-y-empujados/21697#21697) puedes encontrar información similar.