# Dudas acerca de .gitignore

Tags: nodejs, gitignore

Verán, tengo un problema por el cual en mi proyecto monorepo tengo que pasarlo a github, y quiero que no se suban determinados proyectos, para lo cual se supone que debo usar .gitignore.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En este ejemplo, quiero impedir que incluya el fichero yarn.lock, por lo que lo incluyo en gitignore.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero va a ser que el fichero termina incluido.
¿Se me esta olvidando algo? Por cierto, también quiero que no se suba a github el fichero base.js, dentro de la carpeta server. ¿Cómo lo haría?

Actualizo: Tengo en total 3 ficheros .gitignore.
El primero es el principal, que es el que intenta eliminar yarn.lock. Es el que os he enseñado.

Luego tengo otro en la carpeta server, con el siguiente código:

```
./base.js
```

Y un tercer fichero .gitignore en la carpeta client, con este código:

```
node_modules
```

Y este último fichero si que me funciona, mientras que los 2 primeros no.

Comment: Dentro del `.gitignore`  tienes que poner los nombres de los archivos o carpetas que no quieres seguir con git. Pero si esos archivos ya los habías metido previamente al repositorio con un `git add`, el `.gitignore` no tendrá efecto sobre ellos. Tienes que borrarlos del repositorio con un `git rm fichero` (haz copia del mismo antes en otro lugar, pues se borra también del sistema de archivos, aunque puedes volver a ponerlo luego y ya no estaría bajo control de versiones). Observa que no obstante el fichero sigue existiendo en el repo, en los commits previos.

Comment: @Juanjo He añadido más información al respecto.

Comment: @abulafia Pues tiene que ser lo que dices. Haré lo que dices a ver si se soluciona mi problema.

Comment: No debes tener varios ficheros .gitignore. Solo hay uno en el raiz del repositorio y dentro de él se especifican todos los ficheros que quieres ignorar (como rutas relativas a ese raiz). También puedes especificar carpetas, o nombres sin ruta, o nombres con asteriscos, para especificar de una vez varios ficheros. Mirate la [documentacion](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) para más detalles.

Comment: Por cierto, yarn [**recomienda añadir el fichero a tu repositorio**](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/es-ES/docs/yarn-lock/)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo eliminar un archivo del respositorio de git sin eliminarlo del disco ni perder los cambios?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29498/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-eliminar-un-archivo-del-respositorio-de-git-sin-eliminarlo-del-disco)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la [documentación oficial](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git
> should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected

Lo cual significa que gitignore solo ignorará los ficheros que no hayas agregado ya.

Así que para ignorarlos lo que deberías hacer es crear un fichero `.gitignore` con el contenido:

```
node_modules
yarn.lock
base.js
```

Y luego borrar estos ficheros del tracking de git:

```
git rm --cached node_modules/\*
git rm --cached yarn.lock
git rm --cached base.js
```

Comment: Pues ha funcionado. Aunque es curioso que no necesite incluir la ruta donde están los ficheros. Supongo que solo hace falta si hay varios ficheros llamados igual, para especificar.